# Data passed to vue.js component failed to render but shown in vue devtools

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to pass an object data from Laravel to Vue.js component containing data with eloquent relationships. However, when I access the page, the data was not displaying on the page; and when I checked the Vue devtools, I found the data in the debugger:

[Screenshot to the Vue Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0i8i.png)

Here is my code from `ChatsController` which prepares the data and pass to the view using `compact()` helper function:

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$conversations = Conversation::with(['member' => function($query) use ($id){
  $query->where('user_id', $id);
}, 'member.messages' => function($query){
  $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
}, 'member.user.profile_picture'])->get();
```

Here is my `ChatConversation.vue`, which is supposed to display the data passed from the view:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li class="contact" v-for="conversation in conversations">
      <div class="wrap">
        <span class="contact-status online"></span>
        <img :src="imgUrl()" alt="" />
        <div class="meta">
          <p class="name" v-if="conversation.member.user">{{ conversation.member.user.first_name }}</p>
          <p class="preview" v-if="conversation.member.user">{{ conversation.member.messages.message[0] }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['conversations'],

    data(){
      return{

      }
    },

    methods: {
      imgUrl(){
        return "storage/images/profile_picture/default.jpg";
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

and this is how I call the vue component in my view:

```
<chat-conversation :conversations="{{ $conversations }}"></chat-conversation>
```

If the data is successfully passed, why won't it display? Am I missing something?

Comment: are there some errors in the browser console?

Comment: `member` is an array, no object.

Comment: @Namoshek you were right, I solved my problem by using some nested v-for to display my data. Thanks for pointing it out